# Can I create a "soft" RAID1 array without nuking data?

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, raid1

I've just bought two 1.5TB disks with the aim of creating a 1.5TB RAID1 array.

In my infinite lack of wisdom (and a lack of space inside the computer - it already had 6 disks), I stuck one in, formatted it to EXT4 and proceeded to copy data all over it from drives that I'm subbing out.

Now I want to create a mdadm RAID1 array with its twin disk. I *thought* this was possible. Probably involving unmounting and `dd`ing the content across but I'm *sure* I saw this somewhere before...

But I can't find the tutorial I used the last time I was setting up mdadm so I'm scared. I don't want to nuke 800gigs of data.

Comment: Just for the records, another step by step guide: [How to Set Up a RAID 1 Under GNU/Linux](http://blog.infertux.com/2012/03/29/how-to-set-up-a-raid-1-under-gnu-slash-linux/).

Comment: Since the above url is broken (in 2023) here is a comparable (for all intents and purpose identical) and usable link: https://linuxconfig.org/linux-software-raid-1-setup

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're most likely talking about this http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/238

"Now use mdadm to create the raid arrays. We mark the first drive (sda) as "missing" so it doesn't wipe out our existing data..."

Comment: Yep. Create a degraded array, copy the data to the array, then add the second disk and wait for it to sync up.

Comment: Okay, just read through it twice. Their example is a little more expansive than my setup (I've only 1 partition for starters) but do I have the steps right: 1. Create the mdadm array on the second drive. 2. Copy the data across onto the new drive/array. 3. Add the "old" drive to the array... And then mdadm nukes the first disk and restores the data from the second disk... Sound about right?

Comment: @Oli: You've got the basic idea, but you will need to reboot onto the new array before adding the old drive into the array.

Comment: Woah! This is a really good "cheat" :) I will upvote and "steal" this method as my own.